# How to create/add an encryption/key to a dynamo table via cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kms

see sample dynamodb table , cloudformation template below. when i create the table below, what encrpytion aws puts in place to protect my data, if it does it all? if not, how can i specify in the template below that i want to encrypt my data with a key provided by aws itself, if possible. if not i assume, i will need to add a key resource to this as well.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources: 
  myDynamoDBTable: 
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties: 
      AttributeDefinitions: 
        - 
          AttributeName: "product"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - 
          AttributeName: "model"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema: 
        - 
          AttributeName: "product"
          KeyType: "HASH"
        - 
          AttributeName: "Model"
          KeyType: "RANGE"
      ProvisionedThroughput: 
        ReadCapacityUnits: "5"
        WriteCapacityUnits: "5"
      TableName: "InfoTable"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html), add an `SSESpecification` to your table. So:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources: 
  myDynamoDBTable: 
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties: 
      AttributeDefinitions: 
        - 
          AttributeName: "product"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - 
          AttributeName: "model"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema: 
        - 
          AttributeName: "product"
          KeyType: "HASH"
        - 
          AttributeName: "Model"
          KeyType: "RANGE"
      ProvisionedThroughput: 
        ReadCapacityUnits: "5"
        WriteCapacityUnits: "5"
      TableName: "InfoTable"
      SSESpecification:
        SSEEnabled: 'true'
```

This encrypts the table using the AWS managed encryption key.

Comment: thanks.  I'm little confused , as documentation states If enabled (true), server-side encryption type is set to KMS and an AWS managed key is used. If disabled (false) or not specified, server-side encryption is set to AWS owned key. so what is the difference between AWS managed key vs AWS owned key?